# Select all checkbox reactive forms Angular 8

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I have multiple checkbox arrays in my checkbox form. When user clicks select all button I need to select all checkbox.By using `reactive forms` and `FormArray` this is what I had tried:

**Ts file**

```
  get formReceivedSummons() {
    return this.form.get('receivedSummons') as FormArray;
  }

  formReceivedSummonsItems(i: number) {
    return (this.formReceivedSummons.controls[i].get('items')) as FormArray;
  }

  constructor(private inquiryStore: InquiryStoreService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      receivedSummons: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });
    this.getReceivedSummons();
  }

  getReceivedSummons() {
    this.inquiryStore.summons$.subscribe(result => {
      this.receivedSummon = result;
      this.addCheckboxes();
    });
  }

  selectAllCheckbox() {
    this.formReceivedSummons.controls.map(value => value.setValue(true));
  }

  addCheckboxes() {
    this.formReceivedSummons.setValue([]);
    this.receivedSummon.data.items.map(x => {
      const group = this.formBuilder.group({
        header: [this.receivedSummon.header],
        items: this.formBuilder.array([], [minSelectedCheckboxes(1)])
      });
        (group.get('items') as FormArray).push(this.formBuilder.group({
          name: [x.itemNo],
          isChecked: [false, Validators.required]
        }));
      this.formReceivedSummons.push(group);
    });
  }
```

**Html file**

```
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitSelectedCheckboxes()">
      <ng-container formArrayName="receivedSummons" *ngFor="let summon of formReceivedSummons.controls; let i = index">
        <ng-container [formGroup]="summon">
          <ng-container formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of formReceivedSummonsItems(i).controls; let j = index">
            <ng-container [formGroup]="item">
              <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isChecked"> {{item.value.name}}
            </ng-container>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
      <br>
    </form>
  <button (click)="selectAllCheckbox()">SELECT ALL</button>
```

I got error when I'm try to select all:

> Error: Must supply a value for form control with name: 'header'.

I could not figure out what the errors and could use some guidance and suggestion.

Comment: may I ask why you have several formarrays. Seems to me, that there is only **one** checkbox in each formarray according to your code. Why not have checkboxes in one array?

Comment: because my checkbox are based on object response I got,  here stackblitz demo..https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lntwns?file=src%2Fapp%2Finquiry-response%2Finquiry-response.component.ts

Comment: Yes, and there we can see that you have just one checkbox per formarray, also the header is duplicated. You should restructure your form.

Comment: can you show me on stackblitz please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current setup makes little sense, to have a formarray for each checkbox. You should stick all checkboxes in one formarray. Also the `header` formcontrol is duplicated everywhere. Instead change your code to have the `header` once, and the checkboxes in the `receivedSummons` formarray:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    header: [''], // outside formarray
    receivedSummons: this.formBuilder.array([])
  });
  this.getReceivedSummons();
}

getReceivedSummons() {
  this.inquiryStore.summons$.subscribe(result => {
    this.receivedSummon = result;
    this.addCheckboxes();
    this.isShowResponse = true;
  });
}

addCheckboxes() {
  this.form.get('header').setValue(this.receivedSummon.header)
  this.receivedSummon.data.items.map(x => {
    this.formReceivedSummons.push(
      this.formBuilder.group({
        name: x.itemNo,
        isChecked: false
      }))
  });
}
```

Then make the changes in template, remove the inner formarray:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitSelectedCheckboxes()">
  <ng-container formArrayName="receivedSummons" *ngFor="let summon of formReceivedSummons.controls; let i = index">
    <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
      <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isChecked"> {{summon.value.name}}
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

Then finally the `selectAll` checkboxes, use map as you have, but access the `isChecked` form control:

```ts
selectAll() {
  this.formReceivedSummons.controls.map(value => value.get('isChecked').setValue(true));
}
```

[**Finally your forked STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hepiu1?file=src%2Fapp%2Finquiry-response%2Finquiry-response.component.ts)

Comment: did not realize I got duplicated `header` for each items..let say If I want to submit selected checkbox only how would I achieved this ? by filtering `isChecked` value ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `filter` to get the checked values :)

Comment: Im trying to filter but still got 2 item even I checked only one checkbox ..can suggest the solution ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-udvmad?file=src/app/inquiry-response/inquiry-response.component.ts

Comment: `this.formReceivedSummons.value.filter(x => x.isChecked === true);`